# I have an array, I want to find some element

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

so I have an array and I want to find some element by some property, just once.
The problem is I am not sure what approach is the best here, I have few options.

1. First option - Use .ToList().Find()
2. Second option - Change my array
   to list, but as I said, I am pretty sure I won't need any other list
   functionality, just one find.
3. Third option - Find element in array
   by using for loop

Which method is the best and why?

The best, I mean in time and memory optimalization.

Comment: Call  [Array.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.find?view=net-6.0) or [Array.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0)? Or LINQ's [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) and [First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-6.0) ? Converting to list is the least efficient way because you'll copy the data to a new container.

Comment: You'll want to read up on LINQ basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```cs
var firstMatch = Array.Find(myArray, elem => elem.SomeProperty == someValue);
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```cs
var firstMatch = myArray.FirstOrDefault(elem => elem.SomeProperty == someValue);
```

Both will get the first matching element or `null` if there is no match. If there will definitely be a match then you can use `First` rather than `FirstOrDefault`. It will throw an exception if no match is found.

If there may be multiple matches and you want them all then you can call `Where` instead, which will return an enumerable list that you can run a `foreach` loop over or else call `ToArray` or `ToList` on.

If there must not be more than one match then you can call `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`. Where `First` and `FirstOrDefault` will stop looking when they find a match, `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` will continue looking and throw an exception if another match is found.

It should also be noted that LINQ queries are generally a means to flatten a loop and will perform slightly worse than the corresponding loop. If performance is of utmost importance then you may want to write the more verbose code. LINQ code is generally more readable though, which is generally worth more than the negligible performance gain of the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Array is faster especially if you use the indexer. List is build on top of the array, but have more options for operation on the separate indexes. Maybe you should choose which one is right for you

Answer (score -1):

I usually just use the for loop option. If you don't need a list for anything else, that is probably the simplest method.

Comment: Not as simple as `Array.Find`, `Array.IndexOf` or LINQ's `Where` or `First`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).